# How does TLS record protocol version decide in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm Cha from korea.
(Sorry, I don't speak English well)

My architecure is like below..
API Server > Nginx(forward proxy server, use proxy_pass) > various target company

This is my nginx config

```
        location /proxy {
        proxy_pass $http_target_url;

        root $request_uri;

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;

        proxy_ssl_certificate     /home/ec2-user/[my company domain].pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /home/ec2-user/[my company domain].key;
        proxy_ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;

        proxy_ssl_verify_depth        3;

        proxy_ssl_name [target domain];
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        proxy_set_header       Host $http_x_target_domain_url;
        proxy_set_header       x-target-domain "";
        proxy_set_header       x-target-domain-url "";

    }
```

And I was testing 2 times to another target company using curl.
( curl > nginx > another companies )

And I was analyzing tcpdump by wireshark.

Then First request tls client hello is like below in Wireshark. (nginx > target company)

```
Transport Layer Security
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 210
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 206
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: a720bf2c5849229d626231d2d97770ce56f0a9aa892eb531d1d962f0bf74bd2a
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: b8d975c3bbe498891cfdf702f0509dceeba657fc0a23e9a3c7e3f893b5f43a4e
        Cipher Suites Length: 8
        Cipher Suites (4 suites)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 125
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
        Extension: supported_groups (len=12)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
        Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
        Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=30)
        Extension: supported_versions (len=3)
        Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
        Extension: key_share (len=38)
```

Second request tls client hello is like below in Wireshark. (nginx > target company)

```
Transport Layer Security
TLSv1.3 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 210
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 206
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: d1611d6940be083a1648cbf7690895eb176a485a1fc421e751be4e9fc5c2d4a6
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 6f8324cac87c88de342f7720346326bb56b919d6d733a8ea66ed04b73c68fadc
        Cipher Suites Length: 8
        Cipher Suites (4 suites)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 125
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
        Extension: supported_groups (len=12)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
        Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
        Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=30)
        Extension: supported_versions (len=3)
        Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
        Extension: key_share (len=38)
```

Q1. Why set the TLSv1 Record Layer is version 1 in the first request? I set configure to only use TLSv1.3 in Nginx.

Q2. Two requests are just different having target IP. why first request use TLSv1 , second request use TLSv1.3?

Q3. How does TLS record layer version decide in nginx?

Best regards,
Cha.